# Floating action button is not appear on devices < 5 android version

Tags: android, floating-action-button, coordinator-layout

For some reason floating action button is not appear on devices < 5 android version. CoordinatorLayout and FAB should work well on versions lower 5 as I use support library. What it can be?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/default_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/red"
        app:elevation="@dimen/default_margin"
        />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Refer the sample project here. https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

Comment: I think FAB should be the last child view wrapped inside coordinator layout.

Comment: @ishwor It helps. You can issue this comment as the answer and I'll choose it. Thank you for help.

Comment: happy that it solved your problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think FAB should be the last child view wrapped inside coordinator layout.